# Write-SqlTableData fails with ConnectionToServerFailed halfway through

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a powershell script that uses [Write-SqlTableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) (from the SqlServer module) in three places to write PSCustomObjects to an (already existing) database table, like this:

```
# Note that for some reason, PSCustomObjects created by Select-Object don't always work well with 
# Write-SqlTableData, whereas "[PSCustomObject] @{ ... }" does.
$userDataRows = $users | Sort-Object id | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject] @{
    id = $_.id; 
    name = $_.name;
    employee_num = [string]($_.employee_num) }}

# Be careful with -Force, because the column types appear to be based on the *first row only*, and if it contains 
# a $null value its corresponding column will be of type SQL_VARIANT.
$userDataRows | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance '.' -Database 'MyDB'-SchemaName 'Staging' -TableName 'User'
```

On my development machine, this works without issues, even when importing about 18000 rows. However, on the production machine, the call to `Write-SqlTableData` fails with the following error:

```
Write-SqlTableData : Failed to connect to server ..
At D:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1:155 char:25
+ ... eDataRows | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance '.' -Database 'MyDB' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.:String) [Write-SqlTableData], ConnectionFailureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectionToServerFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.WriteSqlTableData
```

The weird thing is, it doesn't always fail on the same point - usually it fails when importing the 3rd set of data, but occassionally, it will fail during the 2nd set. Also, usually some rows will have been inserted but their count varies: sometimes 99, sometimes 141...

Who can tell me why I'm getting this "Failed to connect to server" halfway through the import?

**Edit:** To summarize what I've replied in some of the comments: There's no networking involved, both Dev and Prod machines use the same SQL Server version, and there's no multithreading involved. Also, the script fails too quickly to run into a timeout.

Comment: Bad internet connection?

Comment: Where does this code execute?  On your dev box, I'm guessing you have a local SQL Epxress or something?  You should also test in a QA environment, where you have another SQL Server, similar to prod (even duplicated from Prod) and then run your code in a similar context to real-life.  This will help you find the cause of the error.

Comment: I would try changing the SQLSERVER time out value and also change change time out in this module

Comment: @Charlieface: Could have been a reason, but in both dev and prod, the script executes on the SQL server machine, so no networking should be involved.

Comment: @FoxDeploy: In both cases the same version of SQL Server is involved, only on dev we're running a Development edition. Good point that there must be a difference in setup somewhere, but I don't think the SQL Server version is it. And we have a DTAP setup, but the Test and Acceptance environments produce the same errors - so for brevity, I left these environments out ;)

Comment: @TheGameiswar: The code fails too quickly for it to run into a timeout, usually within 10 seconds or so. But thanks for all your responses so far, they're greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are there any errors in the SQL server logs? There's lots of server-side issues that could result in dropping the connection from powershell. Running out of resources like ram or disk is a common one. And does `Write-SqlTableData -Verbose` give you any additional output?

Comment: You don't show it in your example, but it looks like multi-threading this command will also almost always give you this error (probably doesn't apply, but double check any tools you might be using)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: I checked the SQL Server logs, no errors there... Also I tried -Verbose, but Write-SqlTableData doesn't write any extra information, sadly. Also, no threading going on, just a simple top-to-bottom script.

Comment: Since we now know it fails fails reproducibly, we know the the issue isn't in prod.  Add that to your question, imho.   Do you use a lot of triggers on this DB for these tables in question?  I've seen similar issues where triggers take a long time to process and then odd cascading failures happen.  Triggers run synchronously.  Maybe update your question and add more detail, like how long it takes until it fails

Comment: Great, now I "un-broke" it, suddenly it also works in Production, without having changed anything in the script. But since it started working out of the blue, it can also stop working at any time. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! Long story short, I now invoke `Write-SqlTableData` with the `-InputData` parameter instead of piping data to it.

That is, changing
`$userDataRows | Write-SqlTableData ...`

into

`Write-SqlTableData -InputData $userDataRows  ...`

...appears to have solved my problem. Also, inserting 18000 rows now takes 2 seconds instead of 3,5 minutes.

Most likely the reason behind this is that changing the Write-SqlTableData invocation to use -InputData means it gets all its 18000 PSCustomObjects at once, and enables it to perform its inserts in a batched fashion. This avoids the “Failed to connect to server” error and gives better performance.

I've written a full explanation [here](https://blogs.infosupport.com/write-sqltabledata-avoiding-the-failed-to-connect-to-server-error/).

Comment: Just throwing my two cents in:
You scould still achieve it with piping by adding "," (comma) at the beginning of the pipe which would execute second part only when first is complete :-)

Comment: I didn't know that, you learn something new every day...